# Load external sheet in Google Apps Sheet addon

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps, google-sheets-api

I created a simple addon for my company. When called, the addon looks at the current sheet, and replaces all cells by their corresponding value in a given glossary.

For example, it will find all cells with value "Brand", and replace them with "123_brand", will replace "Name" by "321_name", etc.

To do this, I use a local sheet ("Glossary sheet"), with all those data on its rows (first column has "Brand", "Name", etc. while second column has "123_brand", "321_name", etc.). All members of my company have read authorization on that sheet.

I load it in the following way:

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createAddonMenu()
      .addItem('Parse sheet', 'parseSheet')
      .addToUi();
}

function onInstall(){
 onOpen(); 
}

var librarySpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID to my Glossary Sheet");

function parseSheet(){
  /* Does the sheet parsing */
}
```

Problem is: it doesn't work.

Right after installing, the "Parse Sheet" button appears normally, everything work. But if the user goes to a different sheet, the addon doesn't work there. Checking the console shows the following message:

> Google Apps Script: You do not have permission to perform that action.

If the user removes and reinstalls the addon in that other sheet, it will start working normally again.

I tried to give edit authorization instead, but it still doesn't work. This applies to all users, even myself.

**Why is my addon being denied access to an external spreadsheet, except right after installing it?**

Comment: I'm guessing that it has something to do with the "Authorization Mode."  Quote:  ***When an add-on is installed from the store, its onInstall(e) function runs in AuthMode.FULL.***  The AuthMode can change after the Add-on has been installed.  Have you read the [Link to Add-on Authorization Lifecycle](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/lifecycle)

Comment: When you say the addon doesn't work, do mean you don't see this particular addon under the add on menu?

Comment: @JackBrown I mean that I see the addon in the addons menu, but none of its functions are there, just "Help"

Comment: @SandyGood That seems to really fit my issue yeah... I'll test that way and see how it goes

Comment: I put the `onInstall` function at the very top of code.gs.  You have `onOpen()` before `onInstall()`.  I can't prove that it's better that way, but there was an issue at one point that I think was resolved by that.  I know it sounds stupid, but there is a low cost to changing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This global declaration is he reason you are not seeing your add-on menu function in your addon:

```
var librarySpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID to my Glossary Sheet");
```

This is global delcaration i.e. not declared in your function. So is excuted when your onOpen() function is called at the time of opening a new document. This is quote from the documentation page

> Warning: When your onOpen(e) function runs, the entire script is loaded and any global statements are executed. These statements execute under the same authorization mode as onOpen(e) and will fail if the mode prohibits them. This prevents onOpen(e) from running. If your published add-on fails to add its menu items, look in the browser's JavaScript console to see if an error was thrown, then examine your script to see whether the onOpen(e) function or global variables call services that aren't allowed in AuthMode.NONE.

The addon is installed and not enabled in the new spreadsheet so runs in the `authMode.None` authorization. In that authorization mode, it doesn't have the permission to open any spreadsheet. So the global declarations fails and onOpen terminates prematurely without adding your menu items.

My suggestion to fix it is the following just move the whole declaration into your parseSheet function

```
function parseSheet(){
var librarySpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID to my Glossary Sheet");
  /* Does the sheet parsing */
}
```

or you can try doing this if you want  `librarySpreadsheet` to be a global variable:

```
var librarySpreadsheet
function parseSheet(){
    librarySpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID to my Glossary Sheet");
      /* Does the sheet parsing */
    }
```

Finally, why does this work when reinstalled? (Already answered by @SandyGood, in the comments!)  When installed, the addon runs in `authoMode.FULL` since it needs user interaction for authorization to install. Quote from documentation

> When an add-on is installed from the store, its onInstall(e) function
>   runs in AuthMode.FULL

Therefore, when it is reinstalled it able to get that global declaration and also enables the addon for that document. Hence, the addon works fine for future runs as well for that document